# How do i remove a part of my string and append it at the back (shell)

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to develop a bash shell script.

My requirement is i have a file

```
ABC-123

XY2Z-234
```

and i want this as the output of my file

```
ABC-123_ABC

XY2Z-234_XY2Z
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use sed,

```
sed 's/^\([^-]*\).*/&_\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
s="ABC-123"
echo "${s}_${s%-*}"
```

Output:

```
ABC-123_ABC
```

In `${s%-*}` the pattern `-*` is matched (shortest match from end/right) in `$s` and deleted to produce `ABC`.

Another way is:

```
echo "${s}_${s/-*/}"
```

where the first occurrence of pattern `-*` is matched (from left) in `$s` and replaced with empty string (delete) to produce `ABC`.